Get Woocommerce products by name and category with wc_get_products()
I have a very simple WooCommerce Product Query - I need one product by name having specific category id.
$args = array(
    'status'     => 'publish', // Only published products
    'return'     => 'objects', // Return the product objects (WC_Product)
    'limit'=> 1,
    'product_category_id'   => array( 6 ), // Filter by category ID
    'name' => 'test'
);
$products = wc_get_products($args);

I found that this doesn't produce the results that I expect.

It returns products with slug "test" and does not check what is the name/title of the product which is not what it should do according the documentation for wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query.

It doesn't respect the category id filter. If there is a product with slug "test" it will be returned even if it is not in category 6 for example. (if I remove the "name" parameter the query correctly returns only products from category with ID 6.


I have read that there could be issues due to some internal WC cache and I have saved manually all the tested products and categories. I have tried with safe mode with only WC, 2024 theme and test plugin containing only the code above.
Am I doing something wrong?

As an alternative, you could try to use a WP_Query instead, embedded in a function, to get the product object(s) from the name and category(ies) ID(s).
Also
function get_product_objects_from( $name, $categories_ids ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $product_ids = (array) get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'  => 1, // limit
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'title'           => $name,
        'fields'          => 'ids', // return
        'tax_query'       => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $categories_ids,
        )),
    ));
    return $product_ids ? array_map('wc_get_product', $product_ids) : null;
}

Usage:
$product_objects = get_product_object_from( 'test', [6] );
echo '<pre>'. print_r( $product_objects, true ) . '</pre>'; // Output product objects 

Tested and works.

Addition:
As it seems that there is a bug related to WC_Product_Query whith your query, you should report it. When this issue will be solved, you will be able to use your code.
Note that both codes are actually effective: Only WooCommerce orders use their own tables when HPOS is enabled and this process took some years. For Products, WooCommerce is still using completely WordPress wp_posts table which handle the product name and for product categories it also use WordPress dedicated tables…

Thank you very much for the suggestion. but what about efficiency (it seems that we do double job here (get_posts() + wc_get_product()) and additionally - in the WC documentation they say: "Building custom WP_Queries or database queries is likely to break your code in future versions of WooCommerce as data moves towards custom tables for better performance. "
